# nosetests is not detecting my testcase that should failed

Tags: python

I am trying to run my first python - nosetests. However, nosetests is not picking up the false value, and is always passing it.

#

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def testCase9p():
    # Open database: qa, and report connection
    db1 = MySQLdb.connect("host1","usr1","passwd1","db1" )
    db2 = MySQLdb.connect("host","usr2","passwd2","db2" )

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    query1 = db1.cursor()
    query2 = db2.cursor()

    query1.execute("select modified from dcp where jobid =7;")
    query2.execute("Select modified from jusage where jobid =7")

    # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
    data1 = query1.fetchone()
    data2 = query2.fetchone()

    if (data1 == data2):
        field1.text = "Pass"
        return True
    else:
        field1.text = "Fail"
        return False
    db1.close()
    db2.close()
result=testCase9p()
```

#

then I ran "nosetests --with-xunit" but the result is not detecting that it suppose to failed. 
(I know from the backend they should not compare, where do I not do correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nosetests is looking for a piece of code to fail. Try changing the following bit of code

```
if (data1 == data2):
    field1.text = "Pass"
    return True
else:
    field1.text = "Fail"
    return False
```

to

```
assert data1 == data2
```